# Tortoise SVN creating and update package

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a trunk and one branch of a php script.  All i want to do is create an update package of files that have changed.

Is there someway to do this using Tortoise SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files that have changed since you branched? [open the log](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html), find the revision where you created the branch, select the revisions and (I think) right click and "copy to clipboard" using the menu. You'll get a list of files in all those revisions.

Otherwise, check out both trunk and branch and use winmerge or similar to see differences.